# WPF create your own type

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to create a template (resource dictionary) for my app. where my type inherits the button type and I then can call it through:

```
<my-custom-type inherit from button>
</my-custom-type inherit from button>
```

And of course in WPF.

More specifically, I would like to create copies of the control in the image below with simple XAML syntax as above.

[image: button]

Comment: Please be a bit more clear, you can certainly create user controls (and even inherit from button, though I doubt you *really* want to do that). Could you clarify where you are struggling?

Comment: Okay, I guess you know that you can create those templates for every widget (type) in wpf. In my app I've created a border with a textbox. But now I want to create type with those widgets. So I can import it and use it so often I want. I hope it was a good explanation ... Well I'll upload a picture.

Comment: I think I kind of get it. Let me know if my answer helps! Also, please edit that comment's information into your post, it does help clarify it. If you post a link to the image I'll upload for you.

Comment: http://de.tinypic.com/r/2zgx2r9/8 Heres my picture

Comment: Answer is still the same, but I added it in for you :)

Answer (score 4):

There are two approaches to this, each with their own pros and cons:

**Templates** allow you to reuse a section of XAML. There is (almost always) no code-behind, and you certainly won't be deriving from `Button`. For example, if you wanted to have a bordered text box repeated in an `ItemsControl`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
    <Border>
        <TextBox/>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Or in a button class you use `ContentTemplate`:

```
<Button ContentTemplate={StaticResource MyTemplate}>
</Button>
```

And you would use it as `XTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}"` in an existing control that used templates. This is *usually* the way to go. Note that the name of the property won't be `Template`, but `ItemTemplate`, or `ContentTemplate` or something similar.

The exception is if you want custom *behavior*, in which case you use a **UserControl**. This technically could inherit from `Button` though you usually wouldn't. Subclassing a basic control should only be done if you are sure you actually want to do that. Once your user control is created, the syntax would look similar to what you have in your question:

```
<local:MyButton>
</local:MyButton>
```

Note that "local" is a made-up xmlns. Your user control would consist of whatever controls you wanted, and you can expose "attributes" to the using code via dependency properties.

Comment: Ahh ... I think I've understand the first example. I will test it :P brb

Comment: Templates looks the way to go.

Comment: @kidshaw Usually yes, `UserControl` is very commonly misused in WPF.

Comment: Exception: An object of the type "System.Windows.DataTemplate" cannot be applied to a property that expects the type "System.Windows.Controls.ControlTemplate".                                       I tried <Button Template="{StaticResource myDataTemp"/> but it gave me this error :(

Comment: @Sens4 Not really what I meant... That property expects a `ControlTemplate` which you *could* create though there is no reason to. I'll add an example that will help. You just need to use the `ContentTemplate`